# WinForms tooltip flips over when tab key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a balloon tooltip control on a form.  If the user enters incorrect information then the tooltip is displayed.  The problem is if you display the tool tip and then hit the tab button the tooltip 'flips' over, is there any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: What kind of form are you using? WinForm? WPF? Web?

Comment: Its a winform, but I have managed to fix it using a var which i set when the tool tip is displayed so that it does not try and display it again, hence flip it.  Its annoying behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be standard behavior, was able to fix it using a var and testing to see if it was displayed already.

Comment: Or you could use this.myToolTip.RemoveAll(); before displaying it. Also stops the flipping over.